# How can I rotate cubemap in shadergraph?

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

I know how to rotate cube map with legacy surface shader

Shader Rotation Matrix:

```
uniform float4x4 _Rotation;
          o.Emission = texCUBE (_Cube,  mul(_Rotation, float4(IN.worldRefl,0))).rgb;
```

RotateCubeMap:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateCubeMap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20;
    private MeshRenderer _meshRenderer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        var rot = Quaternion.Euler (0, Time.time*speed, 0); 
        var m = new Matrix4x4 ();
        m.SetTRS(Vector3.zero, rot,new Vector3(1,1,1) );
        _meshRenderer.material.SetMatrix ("_Rotation", m);
    }
}
```

I tried to recreate it by shadergraph

[image]

but it didn't work!

[image]

I need a result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood what is my problem!

It's because Instead of multiplying `WorldReflect` with `Rotation Matrix`

I multiplied the `ObjectSpaceViewDirection` with `Rotation Matrix`

so I could fix it by using custom function:

[image]

Custom function basic setup:

[image]

use this script inside the shader:

```
float3 WorldReflect = reflect(-ObjectSpaceViewDirection, ObjectSpaceNormal);
OutPut =  SAMPLE_TEXTURECUBE_LOD(_CubeMap, sampler_CubeMap, mul(Rotation, float4(WorldReflect,0)) , 0);
```

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this, but cannot get the cubemap to move. Also how would you control speed with this?

Comment: @LaitonKuu hi you should attach the RotateCubeMap and change the speed

Answer (score 1):

Possibly found a simpler way without a custom function.

Use the `Rotate About Axis Node` and just set the `Axis` you want to rotate around (vertical is Y) to 1 and others to 0.

Connect the `ViewDirection` Node to the `In` and the `Out` to the `SampleCubeMap ViewDir`.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled uppon this thread a bit late, but this could be of help to other people.

I recreated the rotation inside shadergraph. Heres the image:

Basically is just calculate reflection vector between view direction and normal vector, and then rotate about axis, in this case Y needs to be set to 1 and voila. Plug it into a Sample Cubemap.

Hope this helps!
[image]

Comment: Although the image resembles the final result, it would be nice if you could walk through a detailed creation of the graph.